# Instantiate creating 4 projectiles instead of 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a projectile I want to load and fire when I press space. Here's my code for it, along with the rest of my character script:

```
public float moveSpeed = .2f;
public float shotspeed = 1f;
int selectedCharacter = 1;
int selectedProjectile = 1;
string characterName;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-moveSpeed, 0f, 0f);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(moveSpeed, 0f, 0f);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
        GameObject bullet = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Projectile" + selectedProjectile, typeof(GameObject));
        Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Tab)) {

        if (selectedCharacter < 4) {
            selectedCharacter++;
            selectedProjectile++;
        }
        else {
            selectedCharacter = 1;
            selectedProjectile = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i != selectedCharacter){
                characterName = "C" + i;
                GameObject.Find (characterName).GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
            }
            else {
                characterName = "C" + selectedCharacter;
                GameObject.Find(characterName).GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled=true;

            }
        }
    }


}
```

It's like this because I have four different projectiles and selectedProjectile gets changed every time I press tab.

Attached to the projectile is a projectile movement script.

However, when I press space, 4 bullets are instantiated instead of one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't think you've shown us enough code. also, should you be loading a resource every time someone presses a button? wouldn't it be better to preload all the projectiles?

Comment: The code I see only instantiates one bullet. You don't have that script attached four times to something, do you? You should add a small `Debug.Log()` after each time you `Instantiate()` a bullet, see how many logs you will get. If there's only 1 in the log, the bullets come from somewhere else. `Input.GetKeyDown()` should also be correct, only returns `true` in that one frame where the key is down. Your hardware is alright, no loose contact on the space key that causes `GetKeyDown()` to fire four times?

Comment: @mpen I added the rest of my character script.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Just added the `Debug.Log()` and it returns four times. I only have the script added once. I'm at a loss here, my space key works fine, etc.

Comment: what happens if you hold down space? does it keep creating projectiles? perhaps you want a 'keypress' event instead of a 'keydown' event which may fire continuously?

Comment: @mpen If I hold down space it just fires four projectiles, not more than that.

Comment: You can check if that's an input problem specific for the keyboard, replace the `if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))` with `if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` and see if only fires once on the left mouseclick. If it still fires 4 times, there's some crazy logic bug.
@mpen I though so too, but then he must have used `Input.GetKey()` which returns `true` during every frame the key is down. `Input.GetKeyDown()` only returns `true` in the frame the hardware reports the key is pressed down.

Comment: If hardware is not the issue, then i suspect that the script is attached to multiple objects. Do you have other characters? Are you attaching the script in code? In inspector? A fix could be to add a `shotDelay`. But that would just be a work-around

Comment: @ejsd1989 yes I just realized it's attached to multiple characters. I'll have to fix that. Thanks for helping me realize that!

Comment: @quibblify good to hear that you caught it. :P. Hope everything from here on out works well for you :P

Answer (score 0):

**I moved the comment to an answer.**

If hardware is not the issue, then i suspect that the script is attached to multiple objects.

Do you have other characters? Are you attaching the script in code? In inspector?

A fix could be to add a shotDelay. But that would just be a work-around.

I'd recommend you double check that you don't have the script attached to multiple objects.